# Weird characters on mac

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

Since a few weeks whenever some app needs our password our needs our permission for something, it no longer displays it as understandable language, but with weird characters. How can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question?  Seems like it should be on Ask Different or Super User.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a problem with your language for some inputs / options.

Look at this documentation about how to change your language for specific options:

http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11251

Comment: It's on "Nederlands" (our language), so I don't see anything wrong there?

Comment: hmm. you can change seperate languages or am i wrong? (i'm dutch too) is there a kind of reset button? so it's set to default?

Comment: oh allright. yeah that was what i meant. the option 'use same lagnuages for all documents'. i don't know what the problem is then. can't help you with this. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of OSX you are running, you might want to try *Font Book* (in the Applications folder) and specifically search for **Look for Enabled Duplicates**.  Sometimes having duplicate or misnamed fonts can cause rendering problems like this.

There are other utilities as well, such as **Font Doctor** that can do similar (and more extensive) searches.